# Node.js respond with asynchronous data

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, proxy, callback

Recently I started learning a little bit about Node.js and it's capabilities and tried to use it for some web services.
I wanted to create a web service which will serve as a proxy for web requests.
I wanted my service to work that way:

1. User will access my service -> http://myproxyservice.com/api/getuserinfo/tom
2. My service will perform request to -> http://targetsite.com/user?name=tom
3. Responded data would get reflected to the user.

To implement it I used the following code:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var proxy = require('./proxy_query.js')

function makeProxyApiRequest(name) {
  return proxy.getUserData(name, parseProxyApiRequest);
}

function parseProxyApiRequest(data) {
  returned_data = JSON.parse(data);
  if (returned_data.error) {
    console.log('An eror has occoured. details: ' + JSON.stringify(returned_data));
    returned_data = '';
  }
  return JSON.stringify(returned_data);
}

app.post('/api/getuserinfo/tom', function(request, response) {
  makeProxyApiRequest('tom', response);
  //response.end(result);
});

var port = 7331;
```

proxy_query.js:

```
var https = require('https');

var callback = undefined;

var options = {
    host: 'targetsite.com',
    port: 443,
    method: 'GET',
};

function resultHandlerCallback(result) {
    var buffer = '';

    result.setEncoding('utf8');
    result.on('data', function(chunk){
        buffer += chunk;
    });

    result.on('end', function(){
        if (callback) {
            callback(buffer);
        }
    });
}

exports.getUserData = function(name, user_callback) {
    callback = user_callback
    options['path'] = user + '?name=' + name;

    var request = https.get(options, resultHandlerCallback);

    request.on('error', function(e){
        console.log('error from proxy_query:getUserData: ' + e.message)
    });

    request.end();
}
app.listen(port);
```

I wish I didn't screwed this code because I replaced some stuff to fit my example.

Anyway, the problem is that I want to post the response to the user when the HTTP request is done and I cant find how to do so because I use express and express uses asynchronous calls and so do the http request.
I know that if I want to do so, I should pass the makeProxyApiRequest the response object so he would be able to pass it to the callback but it is not possible because of asyn problems.

any suggestions?
help will be appreciated.

Comment: I notice both your `makeProxyApiRequest` and `parseProxyApiRequest` functions are blocking. For both of these, I'd strongly recommend following Node's pattern of `function name(input, callbackfunction)` where the callback is called either as `callback(false, result)` in your function when everything went fine, or as `callback(someerrorobjectorstring)` when something goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you, it is a good idea. but it doesn't solve the problem. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: writing you an answer, but one thing to remember is that the user's request is *always* asynchronous between their browser, and the server they're contacting, so that's not actually a problem. The fact that express forces you to form your response asynchronously is actually a benefit here, so you're not tempted to do everything synchronously instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using your functions to process requests inside your route handling, it's better to write them as express middleware functions, taking the specific request/response pair, and making use of express's `next` cascade model:

```
function makeProxyApiRequest(req, res, next) {
  var name = parseProxyApiRequest(req.name);
  res.locals.userdata = proxy.getUserData(name);
  next();
}

function parseProxyApiRequest(req, res, next) {
  try {
    // remember that JSON.parse will throw if it fails!
    data = JSON.parse(res.locals.userdata);
    if (data .error) {
      next('An eror has occoured. details: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    res.locals.proxyData = data;
    next();
  }
  catch (e) { next("could not parse user data JSON.");  }
}

app.post('/api/getuserinfo/tom',
  makeProxyApiRequest,
  parseProxyApiRequest,
  function(req, res) {
    // res.write or res.json or res.render or
    // something, with this specific request's
    // data that we stored in res.locals.proxyData
  }
);
```

Even better would be to move those middleware functions into their own file now, so you can simply do:

```
var middleware = require("./lib/proxy_middleware");
app.post('/api/getuserinfo/tom',
  middleware.makeProxyApiRequest,
  middleware.parseProxyApiRequest,
  function(req, res) {
    // res.write or res.json or res.render or
    // something, with this specific request's
    // data that we stored in res.locals.proxyData
  }
);
```

And keep your app.js as small as possible. Note that the client's browser will simply wait for a response by express, which happens once `res.write`, `res.json` or `res.render` etc is used. Until then the connection is simply kept open between the browser and the server, so if your middleware calls take a long time, that's fine - the browser will happily wait a *long* time for a response to get sent back, and will be doing other things in the mean time.

Now, in order to get the `name`, we can use express's parameter construct:

```
app.param("name", function(req, res, next, value) {
  req.params.name = value;
  // do something if we need to here, like verify it's a legal name, etc.
  // for instance:
  var isvalidname = validator.checkValidName(name);
  if(!isvalidname) { return next("Username not valid"); }
  next(); 
});

...

app.post("/api/getuserinfo/:name", ..., ..., ...);
```

Using this system, the `:name` part of any route will be treated based on the `name` parameter we defined using app.param. Note that we don't need to define this more than once: we can do the following and it'll all just work:

```
app.post("/api/getuserinfo/:name", ..., ..., ...);
app.post("/register/:name", ..., ..., ... );
app.get("/api/account/:name", ..., ..., ... );
```

and for every route with :name, the code for the "name" parameter handler will kick in.

As for the `proxy_query.js` file, rewriting this to a proper module is probably safer than using individual exports:

```
// let's not do more work than we need: http://npmjs.org/package/request
// is way easier than rolling our own URL fetcher. In Node.js the idea is
// to write as little as possible, relying on npmjs.org to find you all
// the components that you need to glue together. If you're writing more
// than just the glue, you're *probably* doing more than you need to.
var request = require("request");
module.exports = {
  getURL: function(name, url, callback) {
   request.get(url, function(err, result) {
     if(err) return callback(err);
     // do whatever processing you need to do to result:
     var processedResult = ....
     callback(false, processedResult);
   });
  }
};
```

and then we can use that as `proxy = require("./lib/proxy_query");` in the middleware we need to actually do the URL data fetching.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much!. Seems like it solves my problem. Going to implement it now. Your help is very appreciated!

Comment: Hi mike, I tried to implement what you said above. I get the general concept but there are few things I cant figure out. Your wrote in makeProxyApiRequest: var name = parseProxyApiRequest(req.name); where is this req.name coming from? who supplies it? For another question, by doing proxy.getUserData(name); you mean proxy.getURL? and if so where do you supply callback and how you can assign the result into a variable if it is asynchronous? do you get my questions?

Comment: Let me add that part to the answer, cause how we get that is actually really cool.

Comment: and how can you perform this line "res.locals.userdata = proxy.getUserData(name);" if getUserData (which is getURL) is asynchronous?

Comment: figures it out: function makeProxyRequest(req, res, next) {
  // var name = module.exports.parseProxyRequest(req.name);
  http.getURL('https://google.com', function(data){
    res.locals.userData = data.body;
    next();
  });
}

Comment: no. if getUserData is asynchronous, you simply do `app.param("name", function(req, res, next, value) { getUserData(value, function(err, result) { if(err) return next(err); req.params.name = value; next(); }); })` - rely on the callbacks to get you the data OR the error, if error, `next(err)`, if no error, do what you need to do and move on to the next middleware call.